# How to stop queue processing without knowing the number of items that will be processed before-hand?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, producer-consumer

Let's say I'm building a webcrawler in the form of a producer/consumer model.

My crawler has a queue onto which the seed URL is enqueued by the producer.
The consumer reads from the queue, crawls the page for links, and enqueues them after duplicate validation (done using a "*processed*" collection) onto the *same* queue.

My problem is that I will not know how many pages that the seed URL can have. Also, I don't want to keep the crawler running without a limit and want to have a `threshold` of say 500 pages crawled totally.

**My code is as below:**

```
int retryCount = 0;
while(true){
    if(!queue.empty()){
        process(queue.poll()); // assume process method runs in multiple threads.
        retryCount = 0; // reset the retry count
    }else{
        Thread.sleep(1000) // wait for 1 second before retrying.
        if(retryCount == threshold){
            break;
        }
        retryCount++;
    }
}
```

**Case 1:** If my seed URL has say 5 pages, then the 5 pages are crawled and at one point, the queue will become empty which will start the retry logic before exiting the while loop. This also helps me guard against any network delay in crawling ie. it acts like a timeout.

**Case 2:** If my seed URL has more pages say 100, then my queue will be loaded with 100 which inturn will keep loading more pages. Now how do limit the page crawl limit here ?

My approaches:

1. Against each seed URL, I maintain a counter map that lets me know the current pages processed. Based on this, I limit the process calls and then the timeout logic kicks in, and the loop exits. The problem here is I need to make the map thread-safe too which adds more complexity. Also, this approach seems hacky as I depend on the retries for exit rather than a proper closure.
2. A Semaphore with count `threshold` which is checked in the while loop. I `acquire()` every time I submit to `process()` and when it reaches 0, I break from the loop and wait for the processing ones to complete. This will mostly act as an upper bound stop but I will still depend on the timeout logic for the lower bound stop.
3. Using a poison-pill/sentinel, again this will be an upper bound stop. Not sure how to figure it out the lower bound.

**Note:** I really cannot depend on the queue being empty to break the loop as it may cause race condition errors. Also, the queue can handle multiple seed URLs and not limited to one domain.

Please tell me what is the best way to handle this scenario.

Comment: Create a pool queue of 500 crawl-requests?  Anytime a link to a new page is found, the crawl thread has to get  crawl-request, load it with the link and submit it to the work queue.  Whenever a thread finishes with a link/page, it queues the 'used' crawl-request back to the pool.  If the pool runs out, a thread/s wishing to make crawl requests block on the pool queue until other crawls have completed and return some requests to the pool.

Comment: But why would I need 500 idle threads if there are going to be only say 5 pages to be crawled ?

Comment: Why not?  If they are blocked, you will not notice that they are there:)

Comment: Oh ok. But how do I enforce the upper and lower bounds on my threadpool with the fixed size of 100.